# SEO similar website names

Tags: seo

I'm working on a pharmacy website, which name matches several ones in Google. I've read meta keywords are no longer usable, so I tried to be specific on the title name, and meta description.

I've also uploaded my sitemap.xml to the Google Webmasters web, after veryfing the website with my account, but it keeps appearing on **page 6**. I'm using Wordpress SEO by the way.

Say it is called "Pharmacy City", and Google outputs blogs and a lot more which hasn't got very specific metatags, and I'm almost sure they didn't uploaded any sitemap to google. I only guess they are first because they are older pages.

Comment: How long has it been since you deployed your website?

Comment: Since two months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any new site will take time to rank. Site age, trust, and other factors are a huge consideration before a site really begins to perform. It will take time. Expect about a year to really soak in. Meanwhile keep developing your content and site as much as possible to keep it fresh in the eyes of the search engines.

As well, the most important thing a site can do is built inbound backlinks. High quality links are preferred, but moderate links work well enough. Just make sure to avoid low quality links as much as possible. You cannot control all the links to your site of course. Just do the best you can and create a link count/quality ratio that exceeds your competition.

Pay particular to keywords, both trending and long-tail which are the keywords that perform over a longer period of time. For your site, keyword research is likely fairly easy. Use the free tools out there such as the Google search query text box (on the search page) by typing in search terms and phrases and paying attention to what Google suggests. Also use [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/) and if you have a Google Account, [Google Adwords Keyword Tool](https://adwords.google.com). You can also look at your competitions pages source code for keyword ideas. Often sites are not fully optimized so please understand that it is very likely you can do a better job.

Here is an answer that I wrote the other day that may help with SEO. [Website logo text - best tag for SEO purposes?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67266/website-logo-text-best-tag-for-seo-purposes/67269#67269) It is a bit of a mini-tutorial that should really help. Just ignore the title.

Comment: again closetnoc, thanks a lot for your help. I'll check and read carefully those links.